# find slack form of given optimal solution to LP that is BFS

Tags: linear-programming

Given LP in standard form with $n$ variables and $m$ constraints.
And given $(x_1,...,x_n)$ optimal solution that is bfs of some slack form.

How can I find the slack form in $O(n^2m)$?

I know that that the BFS contains at least $n$ zeros (and at most $m$ non-zeros). So I need to do some pivot steps from the initial slack form to get slack from in which all non-basic variables are the zero ones.
Every pivot steps take $O(nm)$, but how can I know that $n$ pivot steps will be enough?

Thank you

Comment: What is a "slack form"? Are you trying to find the simplex tableau?

Comment: yes, exactly.
my main goal is to find solution to the dual problem. and for that I need the coefficients in thes implex tableau